# Is there a way to just remove its trace from CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When we delete a stack from CloudFormation, it clears the resources, but the stack itself is just marked as "Deleted" - not removed completely. Is there a way to just remove its trace from CloudFormation?
I have too many of these deleted stacks cluttering my account. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Just change your cloudformation filter to only show 'Active' stacks and you won't see the Deleted stacks any more.

[image: Screenshot]